# Original Stellar Consensus Protocol Whitepaper

Tags: history, protocol

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of the original Stellar Consensus Protocol SDF whitepaper dated on or before April 8, 2015? It is clear from the [blog post](https://stellar.org/blog/foundation-news/stellar-consensus-protocol-proof-code) that a whitepaper was published on or before this date.

However, the [earliest version I can find is dated July, 14 2015](https://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc440/readings/scp.pdf) and the main one that seems to be in circulation is a [draft dated February 26, 2016](https://assets.website-files.com/5deac75ecad2173c2ccccbc7/5df2560fba2fb0526f0ed55f_stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf).

I'm curious if anyone can share the original dated on or before April 8, 2015? I'm doing research for a university class on how protocols evolved overtime.

Answer (score 0):

here's the oldest blog post from 2014.

https://stellar.org/blog/foundation-news/introducing-stellar

If you scroll to the bottom of the blog page you can sort the posts in reverse chronological order.

https://stellar.org/blog

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The fine minds at wiki is where I always go.  If it’s important, it’s most likely disputed heavily but their format it brilliant in its simplicity.  Right or wrong, the discussion, the disagreement, and most definitely the document will be there.  I think it’s wild those intellectuals go through that day in and out to carry the torch.  Gotta be maddening some days.  Thanks guy!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).